# Is there a difference between the function Odd(x) and ((x Mod 2) <> 0)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Delphi (actually Pascal) has the function Odd(x: integer): boolean which returns true, if the argument is not divisible by 2, false if it is:

```
if Odd(x) then
  WriteLn('Argument is odd.')
else
  WriteLn('Argument is even.')
```

Alternatively one could use the mod operator instead:

```
if (x mod 2) <> 0 then
  WriteLn('Argument is odd.')
else
  WriteLn('Argument is even.')
```

Is there any difference regarding the performance? I'd expect the compiler to generate optimized code for a system function.

I'm particularly interested in an answer regarding Delphi 2007 but if somebody can check other Delphi versions too that would be nice.

Comment: Just my personal opinion, but as long as there are no other x mod n checks with n <> 2, Odd(x) is at least more readable.

Comment: Very unlikely that this will be your perf bottleneck. Given that you should use the clearest. Which is `Odd`. Sad that there is no `Even` to match.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right about the missing Even function. I have typed it quite often and got reminded by the compiler that it doesn't exist. With "modern" compilers it should be possible to implement it as a simple inlined function As for it being the performance bottleneck: No, it probably isn't, but I came  across some code where it was not quite obvious what was going on and I was tempted to use Odd instead of (x mod 2) <> 0 to make it more readable. Then I got curious what the performance impact would be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Odd is the best anyway;

As for `x mod 2` check, the performance depends on whether `x` is of signed or unsigned integer; the code generated for unsigned types is more effective.

Delphi XE compiler:

Odd(x):

```
Project11.dpr.10: if Odd(x) then
0040F327 F645FC01         test byte ptr [ebp-$04],$01
0040F32B 741B             jz $0040f348
```

x mod 2, Unsigned `x` (longword):

```
Project11.dpr.14: if (x mod 2) <> 0 then
0040F431 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
0040F434 83E001           and eax,$01
0040F437 85C0             test eax,eax
0040F439 741B             jz $0040f456
```

x mod 2, Signed `x` (longint):

```
Project11.dpr.14: if (x mod 2) <> 0 then
0040F361 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
0040F364 2501000080       and eax,$80000001
0040F369 7905             jns $0040f370
0040F36B 48               dec eax
0040F36C 83C8FE           or eax,-$02
0040F36F 40               inc eax
0040F370 85C0             test eax,eax
0040F372 741B             jz $0040f38f
```

Comment: It's plausible that, at least for unsigned operands, there would be no measurable performance difference.

Answer (score 7):

Odd generates the best code possible (checking the lowest bit) using the [`test`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction)) instruction with 1 followed by a jump on zero. It has been like that since Turbo Pascal.

Another way to get the same code generated would be

```
if x and 1 <> 0 then
```

but why do you want to write such code when you can write it in a way cleaner way using `Odd`.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler optimise `mod 2` to the same thing? It certainly could.

Comment: It doesn't. It uses `and <reg> $01` followed by `test` if x is unsigned and even more code when x is signed.